# How to display multiples of imported html copies?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, polymer

I would like to make attempt for multiple html imports through a javascript/ jQuery. However, I don't find there are any examples on the internet. Possibly because the html import technology is emerging.

In fact, I made an attempt. However, this does not have to be the guidelines.

```
<link rel="import" class="note-import" href="blah.html" />
<div id="notes">
<!-- Put it in here -->
</div>  
    <script>
        var links = document.getElementsByClassName('note-import');
        for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) { 
            var cont = document.head.importNode(links, true);
            document.getElementById('notes').appendChild(cont);
        }
    </script>
```

The code means I want to display the html(s) (whom are divs with styles and so on) into the div with id notes.

Comment: Why can't you just make multiple `<link rel="import">`s? I don't get the problem here.

Comment: Because without any Javascript, you won't display any of your imported html(s).

Comment: Just put multiple javascript counterparts.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use jQuery to load the HTML into specified divs:

```
<div id="page1"></div>
<div id="page2"></div>
```

and then load content into them. You can trigger this function at any time and ever overwrite the content:

```
$('#page1').load('blah.html');
$('#page2').load('blahblah.html');
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I would rather a better way so that if I specified the <link> tag has certain attribute, then once I changed any of the component documents I am worried at all.

Comment: Unfortunately, I only want one div container to append to.

Comment: @SHY.John then load it into a property to append to a single div

Comment: Actually, I finally managed to do this, partially from your idea of segregating the html(s) into different <articles> (div is possible, but my one is special that I cannot use div, because I have other plugins). The difference is that I used javascript where indicated from HTML5Rocks. The link is http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/